# Is there a way to preserve scrollIntoView behaviour in a PDF?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, browser

I have a page on a website where, when clicking certain words, it uses `scrollIntoView` to jump to other sections of the page.

When printing the page as a PDF (using Chrome by doing a browser print and changing the destination to PDF) the scrollIntoView behaviour is, obviously, lost.

But I've seen PDFs that have a table of contents before, so I know that linking through the document is possible, but is there any way to get that linking to occur when using Chrome's webpage to PDF functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `href="#other-elements-id"` on a link to make that link scroll to it ([linking to another section on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Linking_to_another_section_on_the_same_page)). This will still work if you print the page as PDF in Chrome.

If you add an event listener you can prevent this default behavior and still use `scrollIntoView` while you're in the browser instead of the PDF.

```js
var link = document.getElementById('link');
var section = document.getElementById('section');

link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  section.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
});
```

```css
.spacer {
  height: 5000px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="#section">Go to section at the bottom</a>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div id="section">This is a section at the bottom</div>
```

[Codepen example.](https://codepen.io/systimotic/pen/ExYwRrB) Print the output iFrame as PDF to see the link in PDF in action.